# 'missing destination file operand' error while attempting 'stack exec install ...'

Tags: haskell-stack

I am attempting to install Hackage's `servant-auth-server` package using `stack exec install servant-auth-server`, which has worked for me with other packages.

However, with `servant-auth-server` I get an error.

```
$ stack exec install servant-auth-server
/run/current-system/sw/bin/install: missing destination file operand after 'servant-auth-server'
Try '/run/current-system/sw/bin/install --help' for more information.
```

**What is the cause of this error?**

**How can I install `servant-auth-server`?**

---

EDIT

Running the command `$ stack install servant-auth-server` also does not work as shown below.

```
$ stack install servant-auth-server

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for servant-auth-server-0.3.0.0:
    servant-auth must match ==0.2.*, but the stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.2.7.0)

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /home/matthew/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml:
- servant-auth-0.2.7.0

You may also want to try the 'stack solver' command
Plan construction failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The command likely ought to be `stack install servant-auth-server`

Comment: Running that command I get a 'build plan exception' error (question has been edited to show that).

Comment: The issue is that the snapshot does not specify a version of servant auth.  Did you try the "Recommended action"?  That should resolve it, that is what it is there for.  An alternative approach is to just do `stack install servant-auth-server servant-auth`, will pick the most recent version of both.